# Queriyng embedded schema without using fragment

Tags: elixir, ecto

Suppose we have the schemas:

```
schema "organization" do
  embeds_one :details, Detail

  timestamps()
end

# Detail schema
embedded schema do
  field :name, :string
  field :description, :string
end
```

The `details` field is stored in database as a jsonb field.

Now let's say I want to query an organization by its name, the only way currently I can do is using fragments:

```
Organization
|> where([org], fragment("details->>'name' = ?", ^organization_name))
|> Repo.one()
```

Is there any built in way you can do this without using a fragment?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use `fragment/1`. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html

Comment: The reason you need to use a fragment here is that is postgres-specific syntax, and [tag:ecto] does its best to stay DB-agnostic.

Comment: databases such as mysql also have json fields type, then I guess there are some that don't?

Comment: JSON fields support in _MySQL_ is [very different](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html), also _MSSQL_ has its own caveats... I am not a DB professional by any mean, but I’d guess the cross-RDBMS support for JSON queries _might_ happen to appear in [tag:ecto], but it requires some time.